# WCF Data Service, serialize additional properties from Entity Framework partial classes

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I'm on the process of creating an API in much the same way [Hanselman showed it could be done for Stackoverflow](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx). I have a bunch `EntityObject` Entity Framework generated classes and a `DataService` thingy to serialize them to Atom and JSON. I would like to expose some generated properties via the web service. Think FullName as generated by concatenating First- and LastName (but some are more complex). I have added these to a partial class extending the Entity Framework EntityObject and given them the `[DataMember]` attribute, yet they don't show up in the service. Here's an example attribute (`set` is thrown in for good measure, doesn't work without it either):

```
[DataMember]
public string FullName
{
    get
    {
        return (this.FirstName ?? "") + " " + (this.LastName ?? "");
    }
    set { }
}
```

According to [these](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataservices/thread/66b44cd7-2744-47f6-81f3-9bca5205a616) [discussions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/8115cf34-4527-4302-9123-0dce010629e0) on MSDN forums, this is a known issue. Has anyone found good workarounds or does anyone have suggestions for alternatives?

Comment: Not the answer, but as a matter of style you don't need to say `Attribute` when you are using an attribute.  `[DataMember]` is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue exposing Entity objects over a WCF service and used the workaround you linked to [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/8115cf34-4527-4302-9123-0dce010629e0) which is to add the following attribute to the properties to force them to be serialized.

```
[global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
```

I haven't found any 'nicer' ways of getting this working.

For example, given an entity called Teacher with fields Title, Forenames and Surname you can add a partial class for Teacher something like:

```
public partial class Teacher
{
    [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()] 
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", Title, Forenames, Surname); }
        set { }
    }
}
```

Then as long as your WCF Service interface references this class then the extra properties are serialised and available for consumers of the service.

e.g.

```
[OperationContract]
List<Teacher> GetTeachers();
```

Comment: hm, doesn't seem to be working though. What entities are you serilizing?

Comment: I've added a more detailed example to the answer above.

Comment: I think this requires EF4 to work. @Nelson - can you confirm that you are have .NET framework 4.0?

Comment: This answer is specific to WCF Services, not WCF Data Services.